# "Nearly" Harmonic Series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

It's well known that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1+\varepsilon}} < \infty, \ \forall \varepsilon >0.
$$

What happens if we replace $\varepsilon$ with $\varepsilon_n \downarrow 0$?

WolframAlpha says 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1+\varepsilon_n}}
$$

converges for
$$
\varepsilon_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\log(n+1)}}
$$

and diverges for
$$
\varepsilon_n = \frac{1}{\log(n+1)}.
$$

So the question is: can we find a "borderline" decrease rate such that the series converge for $\varepsilon_n$ approaching zero slower than it and diverges if $\varepsilon_n$ decreases faster?

Comment: yes, thanks @vadim123.

Comment: Isn't this really just asking about the borderline of convergence for the general series $\sum a_n$, since we can just take $\epsilon_n = \log a_n / \log n - 1$?  Are you aware of the divergence of, say, $\sum 1/(n \log n \log \log n \log \log \log n)$?

Comment: @ErickWong, I see what you mean. But the general case does not have a "borderline" in the sense of vadim123's answer below. I was thinking about families of series $\sum a_n(s)$, for $s \in A \subset \mathbb{R}$. I do recognize this is not clear in the question. :-)

Comment: That's why I asked about $\sum 1/n \log n \log \log n$ and family.  It seems to me that the general case has a series of "borderlines" at different scales, starting with $1/n^s$, $1/n (\log n)^s$, $1/n \log n (\log \log n)^s$, etc.  I don't see a distinction between these and the border between $\epsilon_n = 1/\log n$ and $\epsilon_n = 1/(\log n)^s$, which could be refined in a very analogous manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int \frac{1}{x^{1+1/\ln(x)}}dx=\int\frac{dx}{x}(1/x)^{(1/\ln x)}$$

Set $u=\ln x$, then $x=e^u$ and $1/x=e^{-u}$ so the integral becomes $$\int du (e^{-u})^{1/u}=\int e^{-1}du$$

which is divergent.  Replacing $1/\ln x$ with $(1/\ln x)^s$ will be divergent (resp. convergent) if $s\ge 1$ (resp. $s<1$).

Comment: Easier: $x^{1+1/\ln x} = ex$.

Answer (score 1):

Use limit comparison test with harmonic series. We have
$$\dfrac{1/n}{1/n^{1+{1/\log(1+n)}}} = n^{1/\log(1+n)} \to e$$